# Change date format of a list field in Mailchimp Campaign (NOT API)

Tags: date, format, mailchimp, reformatting

I'm trying to create an email to go out to our students that will include their first day of classes. I can get the date inserted in mm/dd/yyyy format (eg. 01/07/2019), but I would like it in word format (eg. January 7, 2019) and I cannot figure out how to re-format the date.

I haven't found any similar enough questions anywhere - in Mailchimp help, on StackOverflow, or elsewhere, but this doesn't seem that odd a thing to want, so I must be missing something?

Things that have NOT worked (mergetag: "START"):

`*|START:m/d/y|*
*|START(m/d/y)|*
*|START(TEXT)|*
*|START:l F jS, Y|*
*|START:DATE:l F jS, Y|*
*|START(DATE:l F jS, Y)|*
*|START:FORMAT:l F jS, Y|*
*|FORMAT|START:l F jS, Y|*
*|FORMAT:l F jS, Y|**|START|**|END:FORMAT|*
date_format(l F jS, Y *|START|*)
string date ( string $format[l F jS, Y *|START|*])`

You can probably see where I started trying things I don't really understand!

ALTERNATIVELY: is there a quick "code" for inserting the name of an interest group that someone is in? Thankfully I only have so many dates I need to work with - but they do batch change every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

This is very late to the party, so probably for future refence.

I think it is not possible with the existing formats.

I would try to deliver the field in the desired format and on the "Audience"m  tab look for the "Settings"  - "Audience fields and *|MERGE|*  Tags".
Here add a field with an appropriate name and make it a text field.

In the import file name the field like the created field and import.

Hope it  helps someone.

Jeroen